# Style elements according to attribute value in javascript

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I am planning to use the same XHTML5 file for data storage AND display. At design time, the file will be viewed in browser. At compile time, it will be parsed to generate UI content.

I want to store color data as an attribute of some list items. Then, when the page is loaded, the color data from each of these list items should be "transfered" to the background color of the item, so that I can check the colors visually in the browser, and have the hex-string easily parseable from the XHTML.

What I already have (just one line of each part):

```
(...)
<body>
    <ul>
        <li data-color="#ffeeaacc">EMG</li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        $('a[data-color]').??????
    </script>
</body>
```

I am very very n00b in javascript and Jquery, and cannot figure out what should I do from now. The end result should be equivalent to:

`<li data-color="#ffeeaac" style="background: #ffeeaacc">EMG</li>`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#ffeeaacc` is not a valid HEX color. HEX colors contain only three pairs of two-digit numbers, not four.

http://jsfiddle.net/CQqRX/1/

```
$('*[data-color]').each(function(i, e){
    $(e).css('background-color', $(e).data('color'));
});
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't realize jQuery handled data-* attributes using the .data() method like that. +1

Comment: I think this is the most canonical answer (it worked great), and additionally mentioned my mistake (I'm coming from a rgba-world...)

Comment: Glad to help you. (If you want to work with RGBA colors, this should work too: http://jsfiddle.net/CQqRX/3/ . At lest with newer browsers)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('li[data-color]').each(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', $(this).attr('data-color'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

cYou should use something like that:

```
jQuery('li[data-color]').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).css({'background-color':jQuery(this).data('color')});
});
```

You'll have to use this once DOM is loaded

Comment: Please have a read of the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page, for guidance on how to format your answers.

Comment: If the JavaScript is located after the HTML source, you don't have to wait until DOM is completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This should works fine for you
http://jsfiddle.net/zrARP/

```
$('li[data-color]').each(function (){
    var color = $(this).data("color");
    $(this).css('background-color',color);
})​
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers previously provided rely on 2 thing:

- There should be a `data-color=""` attribute defined on the list item
- All list items should get coloured if they have the attribute defined

This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/Jt3dX/ demonstrates

- how you can selectively get only a group of list items coloured by setting the `class="color-this-list"` on the container within which you want the list items coloured
- how you can set a default colour to list items without the `data-color` attribute

Comment: I appreciate your interest, but actually I want exactely the behavior provided by the previous answers. Anyway, I might come back in the future to look at these more general ways of doing this. Thanks!